# Replace dates in a file with timestamp using awk and mktime

Tags: regex, linux, unix, awk, gawk

I have a large CSV file with dates stored as YYYY-MM-DD. I need to convert these to timestamps. For the sake of conversion, I assume that the time was noon on all dates.

I'm trying to use a gawk script like

```
gawk '{
    print gensub(/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})/, mktime("\\1 \\2 \\3 12 0 0"), "g");
}' file.csv
```

But for some reason mktime always returns -1 for the value. I know I could do this better with a Python script, but just for learning purposes, I'm wondering why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are close, try this:

```
awk '{
print  mktime(gensub(/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})/, "\\1 \\2 \\3 12 0 0", "g")); 
}'
```

example:

```
kent$  echo "2008-10-31"|awk '{
print    mktime(gensub(/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})/, "\\1 \\2 \\3 12 0 0", "g")); 
}'   
1225450800
```

Comment: thanks! the problem is that I need to replace them in-line with the other csv elements. how would i do that?

Comment: first get those `YYYY-MM-DD` string, calculate timestamp by mktime for each, and replace.

Comment: How can I get it to extract each string in the line? The problem is that each line may have multiple occurrences of dates, and I need to convert each one individually.

Comment: @Glen Can you post some sample data?